# What level of security clearance (if any) did the past first ladies have?

Tags: united-states, president

Did past first ladies have security clearance? If yes, what level?

Clarification:
I know that the position of first lady does not by itself call for security clearance. I'm just asking if it ever happened in the past that the wife of the sitting president received a security clearance during her husband's presidency.

Answer (score 7):

The first lady does not receive any security clearance. No previous first lady has ever received security clearance while she was first lady

The important thing to note here is that the first lady is not an official government position. It is not defined in the constitution and therefore doesn't have any inherent powers. This is important because the first lady is wholly unelected position that is not reviewed or scrutinized by the public or representatives of the public.

Comment: At least one former first lady has gotten security clearance. Not quite what is asked but perhaps worth noting.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt which first lady got security clearance? Do you mean Clinton? She was not first lady at the time she got security clearance

Comment: Yes. I read your second sentence incorrectly the first time.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt oh, I see. It's a little ambiguous. I'll fix

Comment: Hillary doesn't count if she got clearance as secretary of state. At that time her husband wasn't active president any more.